# Getting the Oldest Item in Outlook via Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, mapi, powershell-5.0

I'm working on something that is extracting information from my desktop Outlook application. It works for most of the folders I've tried it on, but for some that have nearly a decade of e-mails, I get a "Exception getting 'ReceivedTime': 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program." This is what I'm trying:

```
# New Outlook object
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application";

# MAPI namespace
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi");

# Folder/Inbox
$folder =  $mapi.Folders.Item('name@email.com').Folders.Item('Inbox')

# Sort by the Received Time
$contents = $folder.Items | sort ReceivedTime

# Get the first element in the array, convert to JSON, and then output to file
echo $contents[0] | convertTo-Json | Out-File C:\Users\ME\outlook_1.json -Encoding UTF8
```

Is there a better way of approaching this? I'm on Powershell 5.1.

EDIT: I've also tried this, which is looping through the array and then breaking on the first instance, but received the same error:

```
# New Outlook object
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application";

# MAPI namespace
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi");

# Folder/Inbox
$folder =  $mapi.Folders.Item('name@email.com').Folders.Item('Inbox')

# Sort by the Received Time
$contents = $folder.Items | sort ReceivedTime

$i = 1
foreach($item in $contents){
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item))){
        echo $item | convertTo-Json | Out-File Out-File C:\Users\ME\outlook_1.json -Encoding UTF8-Encoding UTF8
        Break
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort-Object has both -Top and -Bottom parameters, maybe you could use those to limit the data you're feeding in?

Comment: As a side note, to avoid hardcoding the folder names, you can retrieve the Inbox folder using $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6). ( 6 is olFolderInbox)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, I actually don't hardcode the folder names, this was a simple example to get the rest of the code working. I'm actually using Python to generate the necessarily Powershell, which is taking care of extracting the Outlook items I need and then I do the rest of my stuff in Python because it's both the most familiar to me and I plan on using the API of a few webservices that have Python modules. Among other things, this is going to sync Outlook & GMail calendars!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the items collection using `Items.Sort("ReceivedTime", false)`, then read the first item using `Items(1)`.

Make sure you store `Items` collection in a variable instead of accessing `MAPIFolder.Items` multiple times, otherwise you will get a brand new `Items` object every time you do that.

EDIT: I'm the OP of the question and am putting the correct code here for those who might be as dense as I am and not initially realize what is being said!

```
# New Outlook object
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application";

# MAPI namespace
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi");

$folder =  $mapi.Folders.Item('name@gmail.com').Folders.Item('Inbox')

# Get the items in the folder
$contents = $folder.Items

# Sort the items in the folder by the metadata, in this case ReceivedTime
$contents.Sort("ReceivedTime")

# Get the first item in the sorting; in this case, you will get the oldest item in your inbox.
$item = $contents.GetFirst()
echo $item

# If instead, you wanted to get the newest item, you could do the same thing but do $item = $contents.GetLast()
```

Comment: Can you clarify storing the Items collection in a variable vs. what I've done?  I **thought** I was doing that with `$contents = $folder.Items`, but if that isn't the case then I can definitely see why I'm getting the error.  Additionally, I tried doing `$contents = $folder.Items.Sort("ReceivedTime", false)` but it doesn't seem that Sort is a valid function of the Items object? I'm assuming that means I'm putting it in the wrong place. I tried a few permutations of that too `.sort("ReceivedTime")`, `.Sort("ReceivedTime")`, `.sort("ReceivedTime", false)` and they all give similar messages.

Comment: You are using multiple dot notation - folder.Items.Sort and folder.Items(1) will returns two different independent Items objects. That is why you need to store folder.Items in a variable, call Sort on it, then retiree the first item.